# Magento Mysql database import fails in the end of the process

Tags: import, mysql

I trying to import Magento store Mysql dump file via `Navicat for Mysql` to the new VPS

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
CONSTRAINT FK_INDEX_PROCESS_EVENT_EVENT_ID_INDEX_EVENT_EVENT_ID FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `index_event` (`event_id`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

I've added `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` in the beginning of `.sql file`, and `SET foreign_key_checks = 1;` in the end - nothing changes. 
Also I've tried this: `[Restoring a backup of a Magento database][1]` - the result is the same

> Error at query 9370: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (rain.#sql-7ac4_55, CONSTRAINT
>   FK_INDEX_PROCESS_EVENT_EVENT_ID_INDEX_EVENT_EVENT_ID FOREIGN KEY
>   (event_id) REFERENCES index_event (event_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON
>   UPDATE CASCADE)

```
Error at query 9478: Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
Error at query 9479: Variable 'foreign_key_checks' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
Error at query 9480: Variable 'unique_checks' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
Error at query 9481: Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
Error at query 9483: Variable 'collation_connection' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
Error at query 9484: Variable 'sql_notes' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
```

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Did you drop and re-create your database between import attempts?

Comment: Thanks for replying! No, I didn't. I've dumped working database to .sql file, then tried to import the dump to empty database